# MySQL Grouping With Conditional

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this :

```
+---------------+------+
| timestamp     | robo |
+---------------+------+
| 1518259341785 | A    |
| 1518259341785 | A    |
| 1518259341785 | A    |
| 1518259341785 | RE   |
+---------------+------+
```

and this :

```
+---------------+------+
| timestamp     | robo |
+---------------+------+
| 1518259341788 | RE   |
| 1518259341788 | RE   |
| 1518259341788 | RE   |
| 1518259341788 | A    |
+---------------+------+
```

as we all know, if we group a data and count the rows, using this SQL :

```
SELECT timestamp, robo, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
FROM tables
GROUP BY timestamp
```

`num_rows` will be 4. how can I group data with condition `only if` robo RE = 1 in a timestamp. so that `1518259341788` group won't count / appear. thank you.

update : 
result of grouping without conditional :

```
+---------------+------+----------+
| timestamp     | robo | COUNT(*) |
+---------------+------+----------+
| 1518259341785 | A    |        4 |
| 1518259341788 | A    |        4 |
+---------------+------+----------+
```

expected result of grouping with conditonal :

```
+---------------+------+----------+
| timestamp     | robo | COUNT(*) |
+---------------+------+----------+
| 1518259341785 | A    |        4 |
+---------------+------+----------+
```

Comment: show the exact exped  result please .. what mean robo RE = 1 ?... robo is RE or A ..

Comment: You can't select `robo` as a result column if you only group by `timestamp`.

Comment: @scaisEdge : I just updated my post. expected result added.

Comment: i have posted an aswer  hope is what you are looking for

Comment: Why would you expect a result saying robo A has a count of 4, then there aren't 4 rows with value A?

Comment: We don't know any such thing :-(

Comment: What we do know is that if a non-aggregated column appears in the select, then it MUST appear in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a count of records for each `timestamp` value, but only if the count of `RE` records for that `timestamp` value is 1, then you can do it like this:

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
  FROM tables
 GROUP BY timestamp
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN robo = 'RE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: I tried your solution, here's the result : 

mysql> SELECT timestamp, COUNT(*) 
    -> FROM table
    -> GROUP BY timestamp 
    -> HAVING SUM(CASE robo = 'RE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1' at line 4

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inner join on a subselect for timestamp with just a count = 1 for robo = RE

```
  SELECT timestamp, robo, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
  FROM tables
  INNER join (
    select timestamp
    from tables
    where robo ='RE'
    group by timestamp 
    having count(*) = 1
    ) t on tables.timestamp = t.timestamp
  GROUP BY timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT timestamp, robo, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
FROM mytables
WHERE timestamp 
NOT IN (SELECT b.timestamp FROM mytables b
        JOIN (SELECT timestamp, count(*) FROM mytables
              WHERE robo = 'RE' 
              GROUP BY timestamp 
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
        a on a.timestamp = b.timestamp )
GROUP BY timestamp, robo
```

The results would be:

```
timestamp                  robo num_rows     
1518259341785               RE  1
1518259341785               A   3
```

I am not sure how the results you are expecting is possible.